# Two ways of creating a table with primary key ... which is best practice (SQLSERVER 2014)

Tags: sql-server

Is there any difference at all with the following three scripts, and which is best practice?

```
CREATE TABLE Test1 (
  TestID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  Description NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_AnyNameIFancy] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
  TestID ASC
)
) ON PRIMARY;


CREATE TABLE Test1 (
  TestID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
  Description NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL) ON PRIMARY
```

Comment: Where's the third version?

Comment: I think they both result in the same table, so just go with the syntax you like best...

Comment: In the first case, you can name yourself the constraint in the second one, SSMS will give a name to your constraint. Keep this in mind, it's usefull later to have good names for your constraint.

Comment: @CiucaS - to be accurate, SQL Server itself picks the name, not SSMS. Management Studio passes the query through to SQL Server unaltered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that you are naming the constraint in the first one - that is a very good practice to follow.

They both end up with a clustered unique index.

For single column constraints I tend to write it on the one line...

```
TestID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_AnyNameIFancy PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Comment: Superb! Very annoying SQLserver allows all these different ways. Wish I could greentick all the answers here, thanks everyone. @Daniel, thought there were three ways at first, forgot to change text :-s